# nodemcu _ esp8266 server recieved data from android app and forward to esp8266 client

Tags: sockets, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am new programmer esp8266 with lua. I have 2 esp8266 and 1 android phone. One esp8266 is my server and another esp8266 is client. I want to send data from android app to server and server forward this data to esp8266 client. I programed server and client but i think it's wrong, the server received data from phone but not forward it to client.

The server listen on port 9000 and when received data forward it on the port 9999.and esp8266 client listen port 9999.

it is my esp8266 server code:

Can anyone help me?

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.SOFTAP)
wifi.ap.config({ssid="novin",pwd="12345678"})
print(wifi.ap.getip())

if sv~=nil then
    sv:close()
end

function creat_server()
    sv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
     sv:listen(8080, function(c)
      c:on("receive", function(c, pl) 
        if(pl~=nil) then
          print(pl)
          data=pl
          pl=nil
        end         
     end)
    end)
      if(data~=nil) then
        sck(data)
        data=nil
      end 
end

function sck(data)
    sv:listen(9000,function(cc)
        cc:send(data)
        cc:on("receive", function(cc, dt)
            print(dt)
            data1=dt
        end)
        cc:on("sent",function(cc)
            print("data send!!!!!!!!!!")
        end) 
    end)
end

creat_server()
```

Comment: can i without listening port 9000 forward data to esp8266 client?and multicast join is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your other question which was put on hold, your idea has a little bit problem. The esp which is server can't "Forward" data as you mean it, what I mean is that it can't be server and client at the same time, let it be server all the time. So let's review and recreate the scenario again:

You have android application which acts as a client and it will send some data to server node via POST method, there you get it and store it. you can then get the data on client node via GET method from previous server node. this is one way.

About the way you mentioned, first of all the ports in the code you have provided are different from what you have said in your question, other than that you need to first init node as SOFTAP and get the data and after that config it as STATION and send data via http module.
To simply put it, the code you have provided is too imperfect.

**EDIT:**
You can get all the docs and mini-examples you need from [this site](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/),
and in case you need http module, check out [this part of that site](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/).
[Here's](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/wifi/) the doc indicating how to configure your wifi correctly according to your needs.

P.S. Http module has been added recently to the firmware, in case you want to use it and your IDE won't recognize it's syntax, use [build cloud](http://nodemcu-build.com/) to build your own firmware, it will take only 5 minutes.
Also it was much easier for me to move forward with documents rather than example codes in the websites, it's up to you to chose which ever you want.

Comment: can you explain more about way that you said?how server nod send saved data to other station nod?

Comment: the phone sends data to the server(nodemcu_A) in phase 1. Now you have the data in nodemcu_A and the other chip(nodemcu_B) is going to get the data, so you should init it as SOFT_AP (client) and connect it to nodemcu_A which is server and request previously stored data via http GET call.

Comment: sorry mr mowlaei.have you any code for this?Specially for request data with http get

Comment: nodemcu_B should set in STATION mode for client. in nodemcu_A should  i send recieved data via http or not?

Comment: nodemcu_B:client -> SOFT_AP, it will get the data it needs from nodemcu_A via http GET, nodemcu_A is just server, you just setup a server on it after you have set it's wifi as STATION, https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/net/#netcreateserver